# C# Using Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls in .NET Framework 4.6.1 - Web Browser Control Upgrade

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package, toolkit

My program has been using the Web Browser Control for a while in my program, but it simply does not cut it anymore as it isn't able to work properly with the javascript on most webpages. Luckily, [Microsoft has released a new web browser tool for us to use](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/05/09/modern-webview-winforms-wpf-apps/#k1tUGyc9r39gyqsi.97) and it uses EdgeHTML powered webview. The nugget package installer [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls/3.0.0) does not work in my program, however. When I run that in the package manager console, I get this error

> Install failed. Rolling back... Package
>   'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.3.0.0' does not exist in project
>   'Email Analyzer' Package 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.3.0.0'
>   does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\thood\Desktop\Projects\Email
>   Analyzer\packages' Executing nuget actions took 6.64 sec
>   Install-Package : Could not install package
>   'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls 3.0.0'. You are trying to install
>   this package into a project that targets
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the  package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author. At line:1
>   char:1
>   + Install-Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls -Version 3.0.0
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Additionally, here is the dialogue for the install process

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls -Version 3.0.0 

Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.3.0.0' with respect to project 'Email Analyzer', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'
Gathering dependency information took 1.91 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.3.0.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.3.0.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.3.0.0'
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls 3.0.0' from 'nuget.org'.
GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.toolkit.win32.ui.controls/3.0.0/microsoft.toolkit.win32.ui.controls.3.0.0.nupkg
OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.toolkit.win32.ui.controls/3.0.0/microsoft.toolkit.win32.ui.controls.3.0.0.nupkg 305ms
Installing Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls 3.0.0.
```

Is this simply because the toolkit is not supported for 4.6.1? Rolling my program back to 3.0.0 is not really an option because I use references to `System.Threading.Tasks` which is not available in 3.0.0. Has anyone running 4.6.1 been able to successfully integrate the new toolkit?

Comment: The nuget page tells you that you need to target 4.6.2

Comment: @HansPassant I am now receiving an error when I attempt to drag + drop the new web view control from the toolbox

`Failed to create component 'WebView'. The error message follows:
'System.TypeLoadException: Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Web.UI.Interop.WebViewControlProcess'. at Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.WinForms.WebView.get_EnterpriseId()'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ok, here's the deal, there's two steps to solve this issue. Hopefully if anyone else gets this error my answer will be able to save you all some time. I'll break this into 2 easy steps with links.

1. First you'll want to read [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398202.aspx) on how to update your framework. When you get to the "Target Framework:" dropdown, you'll want to select "Install other frameworks..." and find and download and run 4.6.2. Done.
2. Next, you'll want to see what version of Windows you are running. Follow this: Start > Settings (gear icon towards bottom left) > System > About (bottom of left panel) > Scroll down to "Windows specifications" > Check your version.
   If you are running 1803, great - you're all done here! If you're like me and not already on version 1803 (I was on 1709) go [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and click "Update Now" to download the installer on your PC. Find the installer and run. This will take awhile to finish installing so be patient and plug in your PC if you need to.

That's it. Once this is installed you should be able to use WebViewControl in Visual Studio 4.6.2! Cheers!

Comment: to use the V5.0.1 of the microsoft.toolkit.forms.ui.controls.webview the .net framework 4.7.2 works fine for me. it may not need this newer .net framework but easier since I got the framework from vs 2019 but don't have 4.6.2