# I Can not play in browser game second time on my browser! C# WPF/WinForm

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, web, webbrowser-control

I have a problem with my browser. I play in browser game "DarkOrbit".

I wrote my browser to this game, it is a normal browser without advanced functions.

Look at this now: I can log in my game, I can click start and after that, I can play this game.

It is cool but when I will log out and I even close my app,  if I turn it on again,  the game is not working.

I still be able to log in but after a click on start instead the screen has been loaded, I can only see a black screen and nothing more. I know this problem is totally strange but I don't know what is going on.

Comment: cookies?  read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: how can i delete cookies from this page?

Comment: no idea. please read the topic and update your question with proper code and errors if possible

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the new WebView Control. Microsoft just released it in their toolkit in May. I have a [post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50611822/c-sharp-using-microsoft-toolkit-win32-ui-controls-in-net-framework-4-6-1-web/50614978#50614978) that explains how to integrate the new control into your program. The control is supposed to be fulfilled through MS Edge instead of IE like the older WebBrowser Control, which means the new control is better optimized for modern websites and won't get random script crashes and errors.