# Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Web.UI.WebViewControlSettings'

Tags: c#, wpf

We're trying to use the `WebView` control in a WPF app, but get the above exception at run time.

According to everything I've read, including [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50614978/706346), we should only need .NET 4.6.2 and the latest Windows updates.

However, we are using .NET 4.7.2, and have all the latest Windows updates. I'm using Win7, but other developers with Win10 are also having problems.

I tried installing the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls` Nuget package, but that didn't help.

Anyone any ideas what we need to do to use this control? Thanks

**Update** - Ah, just found [this MSDN page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview) that implies the control is only available for Win10. Anyone able to confirm or deny this? More to the point, if it is Win10 only, is there something that supports HTML5 that works on Win7? The standard `WebBrowser` control doesn't support HTML5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Anyone able to confirm or deny this?

I can confirm that using the `WebView` control in a WPF application requires the application to run on the April 2018 (version 18.03) release of Windows 10 or later. It won't work on Windows 7.

> is there something that supports HTML5 that works on Win7?

I am afraid there is no built-in control available. If your users are still on Windows 7, you may want to look for a third-party browser control such as for example [CefSharp](https://cefsharp.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks, not the answer I wanted, but at least I won't waste time trying to get it to work!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to load a web page in my WPF app on Windows 7.1. I had to install .NET 4.7.2 because of the missing runtime type 'Windows.Web.UI.WebViewControlSettings'. I had installed .NET 4.6.2 before that but got the exception when it tried to load a url. I also installed Microsoft Edge from the Microsoft EdgeUpdate Setup installer. I assumed that was required but didn't verify it worked without it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView.IsSupported` to check if it is available.